# Determine that thread is running or not if using runnable in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have created a program in android for multithreading.

When I hit one of the button its thread starts and print value to EditText now I want to determine that thread is running or not so that I can stop the thread on click if it is running and start a new thread if it is not running here is mu code:

```
public void startProgress(View view) {
        final String v;
        if(view == b1)
        {
            v = "b1";
        }
        else
        {
            v = "b2";
        }
        // Do something long
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                while(true){
                    if(v.equals("b1"))
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if(v.equals("b2"))
                    {
                        j++;
                    }


                    try {
                        if(v.equals("b1"))
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }
                        else if(v.equals("b2"))
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }


                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //  progress.setProgress(value);
                            if(v.equals("b1"))
                            {
                                String strValue = ""+i;
                                t1.setText(strValue);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String strValue = ""+j;
                                t2.setText(strValue);
                            }

                            //t1.setText(value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == b1)
        {
            startProgress(b1);
        }
        else if(v == b2)
        {
            startProgress(b2);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that messy code, an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would do the job you need with added readability ...

It even has a `getStatus()` function [to tell you if it is still running](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html).

You'll find tons of examples by looking around a bit (not gonna write one more here). I'll simply copy the one from the documentation linked above:

---

### Usage

AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method (doInBackground(Params...)), and most often will override a second one (onPostExecute(Result).)

Here is an example of subclassing:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Once created, a task is executed very simply:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a static AtomicBoolean in your thread and flip its value accordingly. If the value of the boolean is true, your thread is already running. Exit the thread if it is true. Before exiting the thread set the value back to false.

Comment: I was thinking about some thread specific method to do the same anyways with this solution is very much possible.Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

There are some way can check the Thread properties

You able to check Thread is Alive() by

`Thread.isAlive()` method it return boolean.

You able to found runing thread run by

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

Thanks